# Identify which application pool is using CPU / Memory

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, application-pools

- We have a web server with many Web Sites.
- Each web site has it's own application pool.
- Currently all application pools use the identity of the same domain user.

When one of the sites starts to use 100% of CPU we cannot see which site is responsible. One solution is to give each one a different identity.

Is there a way to identify which application pool is connected to which site without giving them different identities?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IIS 7.x has a built-in worker process view, including (per w3wp process):

- Application Pool Name.
- Process ID.
- State.
- CPU %.
- Private Bytes (KB).
- Virtual Bytes (KB).

To access this view, simply:

1. Open up the IIS Manager (`inetmgr`)
2. Select the Web Server in the left pane
3. Double-click the "Worker Processes" feature icon in the center pane
4. Voila:
   [image: Worker Process view]

[Technet Reference](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771273(v=ws.10).aspx)

Comment: Nice - i did not know that (or had forgotten it.)

Answer (score 3):

From command line run as administrator in %windir%\system32\inetsrv `appcmd list wp`

This will show you the processid associated with each site that you can compare with the task manager.

Answer (score 1):

Use Process Explorer from MS - the executable details on the process that is soaking up your CPU, will show you the string that corresponds to your app pool.